# OpenTelemetry Operator - Not Able to Inject auto Instrumentation libraries

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry, telemetry

We are planning to use open telemetry as a standard for all our applications and we have installed opentelemetry-operator one of our Kubernetes cluster. otl collector and instrumentation is running fine. When we add annotation(**instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/inject-dotnet: opentelemetry-operator-system/my-instrumentation**) to one of the .Net deployments, it is not able to inject the libraries and showing below in logs. We are running all our deployments/pods with non-root user. Please help how can I solve it.

```
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/7.0.0/lib/net7.0': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/7.0.0/lib': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/7.0.0': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/runtimes/win/native/libzstd.dll': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/runtimes/win/native/snappy32.dll': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/runtimes/win/native/snappy64.dll': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/runtimes/win/native': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/runtimes/win': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/runtimes': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/lib/netstandard2.1/MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/lib/netstandard2.1': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3/lib': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core/2.13.3': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/mongodb.driver.core': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration/7.0.0/lib/net7.0': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration/7.0.0/lib': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration/7.0.0': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64/net7.0': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store/x64': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/./store': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve times of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/.': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve ownership of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/.': Operation not permitted
2023-04-04T00:57:56-04:00 cp: can't preserve permissions of '/otel-auto-instrumentation/.': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: DId you find the root cause of this issue? I'm facing it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because permission issue, you might have defined the `runasnonroot` in your yaml file, this prevents cp action from init-container to your application container. even you configure the `runasuser`, you still got the issue.

[Update on 2024-03-08]

Otel Community has fixed this issue. you could check with this PR https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/pull/2695